# php - Upload .dat file to be stored in json

Tags: php, json

I am trying to upload .dat file, I want to get the content inside the file and have it in json.

I have this code:
HTML:

```
<from action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="fileUpload">
      <button type="submit" name"btnSubmit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
If(isset($_POST["btnSubmit"])) {
      $file = file_get_contents($_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"], true);
      $r = json_encode($file);
}
```

The error I get is `file_get_contents("fileName.dat"): failed to open stream`

I am not trying to upload the file to my server or a folder, I am trying to get the data inside it and store it into json.

Comment: You did not upload any actual file, but the file name only - because you neglected to put the necessary `enctype` attribute on the form.

Comment: I have added the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form .. how do I upload the actual file?

Comment: That is all you need, on the client side, for a file upload form. Things might still go wrong elsewhere - so first of all you should check if an error is reported inside $_FILES. (If you don’t know how, then go read the PHP manual chapter on HTTP file uploads, that explains it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file upload will save the file in the php's defined temporary directory. From there you can either move the file to a desired location, or get the content from it. In your case you can simply get the content by using "tmp_name" instead of "name".

Future more, you have to make sure you have the enctype set in your form.

```
<?php
// check if file is given
if(!empty($_FILES)) {
      // get file from temporary upload dir
      $file = file_get_contents($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"], true);
      $r = json_encode($file);
      // show restult
      var_dump($r);
}
?>
<!-- add multipart -->
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="fileUpload">
      <button type="submit" name"btnSubmit">Upload</button>
</form>
```